# How to refresh an iframe not using javascript?

Tags: iframe, refresh

I have an iframe which I would like to refresh every fifteen seconds, but I'm not sure how to do this or if it is even possible. If it is, how would I go about doing this without the use of JavaScript. If JavaScript is necessary then please post how I would do it in JavaScript. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to achieve this using a meta tag, inside the HEAD element of the HTML file being included inside the iframe:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```

This will refresh the page every 5 seconds. See [the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).

However, using JavaScript, this is the way to go:

```
function reloadIframe() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('my-iframe');
    iframe.src = "http://some/url/";
    setTimeout("reloadIframe()", 5000);
}
window.onload = reloadIframe;
```

This will reload the iframe with ID `my-iframe` every five seconds, by pointing it to `http://some/url`.

Comment: That will probably work, but is there any way to specifically just refresh the iframe?

Comment: Wouldn't that just refresh the iframe if the meta tag was in the head part of the page inside the iframe?

Comment: Other than that, you have no way of executing time-based events without using JavaScript.

Comment: What is the page inside your iframe? Could you add this meta-tag to this page.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish here. If you can edit that page, that page also has a root HTML element, inside which must be a HEAD element (if not, you can add one yourself). This meta tag goes there.

Comment: Well if I have to use javascript will the code be safe? Meaning will it be somewhat tamper proof? And the page inside my iframe is a website taken from a mysql database.

Comment: And the webpage the iframe is using is not one of my own webpages.

Comment: It will be as safe as any code. It's really no danger. What can someone accomplish? Stealing the address of the page? That is still possible even without JS.

Comment: Ok, then how would I do it in javascript? You can just post a new answer if you would like.

Comment: I updated the answer to accommodate for your needs. Is it working for you?

Comment: Except how would i include this for the iframe.src instead of someurl <iframe src="<?php echo $website_pulled_from_database; ?>"></iframe>

Comment: because I know php in javascript is complex

Comment: You won't need to, the script loads the page inside the iframe the moment that page has finished loading.