# What is the right way to call dynamic content (currently using ajax) inside a cached page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, performance

We have a news website where we cache a complete article page.

There are 4 areas that need to continue to be dynamic on that page:

1. View Counter: We add +1 to view_counts of that article when page loads.
2. Header: On the header of the website we check if session->id exists or not if it does we display a Welcome [Name], My Profile / Logout and if not we show Register / Login.
3. Comments: We display the comments made for that article.
4. Track User Behavior: We track every single action made by users on the site

Now the only way we could think of doing this is through AJAX calls:

```
$('#usercheck').load(<?php echo "'" . base_url() . "ajax/check_header'"; ?>);
```

And so on.

This is creating a massive load on CPU, but what would be the right/alternative way of approaching this?

Please see attached:

[image: The load in 60 minutes]

[image: The high transactions on the site]

Comment: You could build yourself a single, combined AJAX request on start. So instead of doing four requests you can do one single request and place all contents manually to the correct elements.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good way to resolve many problems. But Will that be enough?

Comment: What do you mean? It would reduce the requests by four times and would be faster. But it will not fully drop your cpu load. The load will come from loading data from other things, like loading your data from database. If your load is to high then, you need to optimize it or think about faster servers. ;) But you have to load the data in any way, and if your page is cached, ajax seems to be the best solution ... other solutions would be full page cache systems on server side, which parses your document for you. But this is much more complicated and need additional software on the servers ...

Comment: As @eisbehr already indicates, the problem is not the AJAX request but the server script. An AJAX request is just a normal page request for the server and it is even lighter then a webpage request since (most times) no resources are requested after it (images, stylesheet, etc). So test and improve the performance of the server script. And only do the AJAX requests when needed, e.g. every minute or so. Note: when the 4 calls don't use the same data it is micro optimization to combine them.

Comment: @eisbehr combining AJAX requests into one is not a solution in this case as it is micro optimization as msoft mentioned, as the frequency at which these requests will be checked varies, like comments and visits require more iterations than header and carrying out all the actions multiple time will kill the server performance instead. I think in this case, we should rely on node.js or similar server-side script for such petty updates while using ajax for one time update or may be less frequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not have to use AJAX for every possible dynamic content, especially in the case of comments, you may as well load them via an `iframe`.
That way, you are not relying on Javascript to make the request.
It may even work for the counter.

However, you problem is not Javascript, nor the database server, based on what I can see from your graph. It seems to me you have some heavy PHP controllers, maybe you are loading a heavy framework just to have `$session->id` checked.

Further, what do you mean by "we track every single action"? How do you track them? Are you sending an AJAX request from every little thing or are you debouncing them with JS and only sending them one every 30 seconds or so?

My advice is that you consider the size of the PHP code you are calling, and slim it down as much as you can, even to zero if it seems feasible (by leveraging `localStorage` to keep track of you user session after the first login), and maybe loading the counter and the comments in alternative ways.

For example, I infer you are only checking the counter once per page load, ignoring subsequent loads by other users while the current user is reading the article, so your counter may happen to be out-of-date once i a while, depending on your traffic.

I going to explain it better: your page has *n* views, so when I load it, you request for *n* and then display *n+1* to me. While I'm reading, the same page gets requested and viewed *x* times by other users. Your counter on the server has been surely updated to *n+x*, but the counter on my page still says *"n views"*.
So, what's the point in being picky and showing *n+1* to me and the not updating it, thus being off by *x*?

So, first of all the counter controller should be as slim as possible, and what if you loaded it within an iframe, auto updating without AJAX?

[How to refresh an iframe not using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872126/how-to-refresh-an-iframe-not-using-javascript)

That would keep the counter up-to-date, you may render it with PHP just once per page view, and then just statically serve the resulting HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is identified as a server load issue. Let's think it through.

## Scenario 1

First, let's suppose that these four separate requests are completely independent from each-other, that is, they do not read the same data from the same resource. If that's the case, then you have

a. Sending everything together and receiving the answer in a single request

vs.

b. Sending requests lazily, only when they are needed

Essentially, we have lower traffic on the one hand, sending a single request, albeit the response is comparatively large, vs. possibly not even needing some of the requests to be sent. Intuitively, the second seems to be better, as not the request itself is the one that causes the traffic, but the work it causes. However, if you always need to send all four requests, then it's better to send them together.

## Scenario 2

There are common resources to work with. In this case, you need to identify which requests are using common resources and cache those resources. You can apply such a cache at server-side as well, so if the user reloads, your server will have a shortcut for the data instead of having to do the heavy-lifting, but you can also cache stuff at client-side, so sometimes you do not even have to send your request to the server.

## Scenario 3

There are operations that by themselves are very slow. In this case you are better off setting up some cron jobs and repeatedly loading this data into a cache, so your users will load the data from a cache instead of separately triggering server operations that drastically increase server load.

Answer (score 0):

The issue doesn't stem from request division; it lies in identifying the root cause:

1. Determine the server's current visitor count.
2. Assess the server or hosting's capacity to handle this workload.
3. Evaluate the optimization of data loaded via AJAX requests.
4. Verify the database's implementation and analysis for optimal performance.

At times, shared hosting might contribute to the problem.